# App crashes while launching other fragment from existing fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-gps

I am using navigation drawer, Fragment_1 holds a listview which searches for gps location and then loads the adapter. The process works fine if I keep the Fragment_1 open till it loads fully. But if I try to open another fragment  Fragment_2 while Fragment_1 is searching for location or loading adapter, the my app crashes. Fragment_2 holds textview and works fine if initiated seperately.

I am using following code to launch new fragments from drawer

```
Fragment mFragment;
FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
mFragment = new Fragment_2();                                

mFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
.replace(R.id.frame_container,mFragment)
.commit();
```

Comment: please paste your logcat output

Comment: If app crashes then shouldn't you post your logcat error. Without that we can only speculate the cause.

Answer (score 1):

You should do an Async task for loading the list. Before replacing current fragment just cancel the async task. Make sure that you check in onPostExecute if the task is not canceled.

Here you can find an example of loading data async into a recycler view: http://javatechig.com/android/android-recyclerview-example . Have a look at AsyncHttpTask. You can see data is taken and parsed on doInBackground and is displayed in onPostExecute. You also need to add the following to your code: enclose everything in onPostExecute in

```
if (!isCancelled()) {
    /* your code here for setting list adapter */
}
```

override on detach:

```
@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();

    // don't update the UI if user go from this fragment
    if (displayResultsAsyncTask != null && !displayResultsAsyncTask.isCancelled())
        displayResultsAsyncTask.cancel(true);
}
```

So your code should look something like that:

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment {
    // declare an async task in your fragment
    private AsyncTask displayResultsAsyncTask = null;
    /* other data here */

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /* your code for onCreate */
        GetAndDisplayResults(); // call display results
    }

    public void GetAndDisplayResults() {
        displayResultsAsyncTask = new AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer>() {
            @Override
            protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
                Integer result = 0;

                // get and parse data, also set result

                return result;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
                if (!isCancelled()) {
                    // if task wasn't stopped 
                    if (result == 1)
                        SetYourList(); // set your list adapter based on results returned from doInBackground
                }
            }
        }.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();

        // don't update the UI if user go from this fragment
        if (displayResultsAsyncTask != null && !displayResultsAsyncTask.isCancelled())
            displayResultsAsyncTask.cancel(true);
    }
}
```

The list used to save your data can be declared globaly and accesed from both doInBackground and onPostExecute or can be pased to onPostExecute as a param.

Comment: No sense in doing that if fragment need to be removed.

Comment: I am using retrofit for listview loading, can you tell me how to achieve this?      the app crashes after it finds the location and tries to load the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you are trying to `commit` `fragmentTransaction` in one of the `onCreate`, `onResume` methods which is causing exception `IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState` due to `activity state loss`. Please check whether you are doing in these functions.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes I am calling it in my onCreate, what can be the possible solution to this?

Comment: `onPostResume()` will be the solution for you

Comment: I am using retrofit to load my listview , can you pleae tell me what can be done in this case.

Comment: I haven't used retrofit but understand the flow and implement the things accordingly. Flow is that during activity starting, you should not commit transactions. If you are using some webservice for response, then on receiving the response, you should commit the things